# Recibir correo electrónico en C#

Tags: c#, email

Quiero hacer un programa con C# que pueda recibir mensajes. El que he hecho es enviar mensajes o email y funciona bien tanto en modo consola como en Windows Forms.

Lo que no encuentro códigos que sirva para recibir email.

Uso una cuenta gmail. Hay que tener claro activar dicha seguridad o no podrás enviar o recibir email con tus propios programas.

Si le pican la curiosidad algunos visitantes, les entrego el código fuente en modo consola para que se envien mensajes así mismos y prueben. Recuerda que quier saber del POP3 para recibir mensajes a ver quien sabe hacer y que funcione.

Acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras.
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código fuente C#:

```
 // Activar / desactivar Acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras en Google.
// https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace Enviar_e_mail_Consola_03_cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string usuario, contraseña, destinatario, asunto, mensaje;

            // Título de la ventana.
            Console.Title = "Enviar e-mail con Consola C#";

            // Tamaño ventana consola.
            Console.WindowWidth = 80; // X. Ancho.
            Console.WindowHeight = 40; // Y. Alto.

            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tEnviar Correo Electrónico");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------");


            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.Write("\t\tIngresar correo electrónico o mensaje: ");
            usuario = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("\t\tIntroducir contraseña: ");
            contraseña = leerPassword();


            Console.Write("\t\tDestinatario: ");
            destinatario = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("\t\tAsunto: ");
            asunto = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("\t\tMensaje: ");
            mensaje = Console.ReadLine();

            MailMessage correo = new MailMessage(usuario, destinatario, asunto, mensaje);

            SmtpClient servidor = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            servidor.Port = 587;
            NetworkCredential credenciales = new NetworkCredential(usuario, contraseña);
            servidor.Credentials = credenciales;
            servidor.EnableSsl = true;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enviando correo...");
                servidor.Send(correo);
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tCorreo enviado satisfactoriamente.");
                correo.Dispose();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tNo se ha enviado el correo.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        // A la hora de introducir la contraseña, se sustituye por asterístos (*) en pantalla.
        public static string leerPassword()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            do
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    sb.Append(cki.KeyChar);
                    Console.Write("*");
                }

                else
                    break;

            } while (true);
            Console.WriteLine();
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor es usar un componente y para eso busca en nuget:

[Mail.dll - .NET email component (IMAP, POP3, SMTP)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mail.dll/)

Tembien te recomiendo usar  [AE.Net Mail.](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail) lo cual es una libreria de cliente POP/IMAP para C#.

Ambas, son bien fáciles de utilizar, solo lee el readme y un poco de la documentación y seras un genio, así no tendrás que reinventar la rueda de nuevo.

Suerte!

Comment: Gracias. lo tendré en cuenta si no soy capaz de hacerlo sin librerías externas.

Answer (score 0):

Justo aquí explico como hacer un formulario de contacto para recibir correos

[Formulario de Contacto con Recaptcha Asp.Net](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2012/07/formulario-de-contacto-con-recaptcha.html)

Agregas un archivo de configuración para agregar los datos de correo(recomiendo hacerlo en  el appconfig para si en un futuro necesitas cambiar credenciales solo modificas este archivo)

```html
<appsettings>
<add key="To" value="TUCORREO@gmail.com">
</add></appsettings>
<system.net>
<mailsettings>
 <smtp>
   <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="TUPASSWORD" username="TUCORREO@gmail.com" enablessl="true" port="587">
 </network></smtp>
</mailsettings>
</system.net>
```

Tu código quedaria algo así :

```
   private void Enviar(string titulo, string nombre, string correo, string mensaje)
```

{

```
   if (Page.IsValid)
   {
       string to = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["To"];
       MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
       mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
       mail.From = new MailAddress(correo, nombre);
       mail.Subject = titulo + " " + correo;
       mail.Body = mensaje + "\n\n" + nombre + "\n" + correo;

       SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
       smtp.Send(mail);


       lblaviso.Text = "Mensaje Enviado gracias por tomarse el tiempo de escribir...!";
   }
   else
   {          
       lblaviso.Text = "No has escrito correctamente el codigo de verificacion";

   }
```

}

Comment: Buenas: Lo voy probar y te respondo.